# Best-response function in two-player games

Tags: game-theory

Given $x_i, x_j \in [0,1]$, and a payoff function $u_i(x_i, x_j) = (\theta_i + 3x_j - 4x_i)x_i$ if $x_j < 2/3$, and $= (3x_j-2)x_i$ if $x_j \geq 2/3$. My question is I don't understand why we have the best-response function $b_i(x_j) = {1}$ when $x_j > 2/3$?

**My argument.** For $x_j < 2/3$, $\partial(u_i)/\partial(x_i) = \theta_i + 3x_j - 8x_i = 0 \iff x_i = (3x_j + \theta_i)/8$. For $x_j \geq 2/3$, $\partial(u_i)/\partial(x_i) = 3x_j - 2 = 0 \iff x_j = 2/3$ for every $x_i \in [0,1]$.

Shouldn't this imply player i's pure best response function is: $b_i(x_j) = [0, 1]$ if $ x_j \geq 2/3$, $=(\theta_i + 3x_j)/8$ if $x_j < 2/3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$u_i(x_i, x_j) = \begin{cases}(\theta_i + 3x_j - 4x_i)x_i &\text{if } \quad x_j < \frac{2}{3}\\ (3x_j-2)x_i &\text{if } \quad x_j \ge \frac{2}{3}\end{cases}  $$

for a given $x_j$ the best response correspondence (please notice that there is no reason that the best response be a function, for a given strategy, there is a set of best actions, thus they call it correspondence instead) for player $i$ can be obtained

$$\frac{\partial u_i(x_i, x_j)}{\partial x_i} =0= \begin{cases}(\theta_i + 3x_j - 8x_i) &\text{if } \quad x_j < \frac{2}{3}\\ (3x_j-2) &\text{if } \quad x_j \geq \frac{2}{3}\end{cases}$$

If $x_j < \frac{2}{3}$ the maximum of $u_i$ happens at either $x_i=0,1,\frac{\theta_i+3x_j}{8}$ (from the Fundamental theorem of calculus).

$$u_i(x_i, x_j) = \begin{cases}\theta_i + 3x_j - 4  &\text{at} \quad x_i=1 \\0 &\text{at} \quad x_i=0 \\ \left(\frac{\theta_i + 3x_j}{4}\right)^2 &\text{at} \quad x_i=\frac{\theta_i+3x_j}{8} \end{cases}$$

Here best response is $x_i=1$ if $\left(\frac{\theta_i + 3x_j}{4}\right)^2<\theta_i + 3x_j - 4$ and $x_i=\frac{\theta_i+3x_j}{8}$ otherwise. For the second case there is a subtle difference, our objective is linear. The player $i$ does not have the ability to enforce the choice of the player $j$ (so $x_j=\frac{2}{3}$ that we obtain from critical point of utility function, is not in the authority of player $i$) best response is either $x_i=0,1$, please notice that we have a linear objective here, the slope of the line decides the fate of $u_i$ and thus the strategy of the player $i$.

$$u_i(x_i, x_j) = \begin{cases}3x_j-2  &\text{at} \quad x_i=1 \\0 &\text{at} \quad x_i=0 \end{cases}$$

Therefore the best strategy here is $x_i=1$, because the slope of the line $(3x_j-2)$ is a positive value for $x_j>\frac{2}{3}$ thus the player  $i$ gains profit by increasing $x_i$ in $(3x_j-2)x_i$. But the player $i$ can not exceed $x_i=1$ and thus $x_i=1$ is the best response here.

P.S. in the first part of solution, the best response $x_i=\frac{\theta+3x_j}{8}$ must satisfy the constraint $x_i\in[0,1]$, therefore $\theta+3x_j\le 8, \forall x_j \in [0,\frac{2}{3}]$ which results in $\theta\le6$ and by similar argument $\theta+3x_j\ge 0, \forall x_j \in [0,\frac{2}{3}]$ which results in $\theta \ge 0$. Also it is noteworthy that the inequality $\left(\frac{\theta_i+3x_j}{4}\right)^2>(\theta_i+3x_j-4)$ always holds true here, I live it to reader to prove it (simply plot the graphs, or check algebraically).

Comment: Thank you so much for your very clear explanation. It makes perfect sense to me now. I have a very quick (and possibly minor) question: does the domain of $\theta$ have to be $[0, 6]$ for the best-response function to be well-defined? Or it can only be from $[0, 5]$?

Comment: Happy to be helpful, can you elaborate about being well defined, what do you mean by "well defined"?

Comment: By that, I mean without $\theta$ in any of those two ranges, we don't have a best-response function that you showed above.

Comment: I thought you are talking about continuity or differentiability. Why $\theta$ must exist, I don't see a reason on the necessity of existence of $\theta$, you can put $\theta=0$ and still the results hold.

Comment: Oh, because the original solution said "if $\theta\in [0,6]$, then we have the best response function that comprises of 3 parts: one is $(3x_j + \theta_i)/8$ for $x_j < 2/3$, $= [0, 1]$ for $x_j = 1$, and $= {1}$ for $x_j > 2/3$.  So I am not sure why it restricts $\theta$ to be in that range.

Comment: Can you kindly give this problem a try:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3561832/best-response-function-of-piecewise-payoff-function 
I am even more puzzled by the domain of player 1's best response function.

Comment: Awww, you are right, now i got it, please notice one of the best responses when $x_j<\frac{2}{3}$ is $\theta_i + 3x_j - 4$, if $\theta$ does not exist, then this quantity will always be negative. to ensue that we always have a three part best response, we must put some constraint on $\theta$, now just have to figure out why the specific range $[0,6]$?

Comment: Okay, i edited the solution. Now it addresses $\theta$ too.

Comment: Awesome! I noticed the fact that the solution must be $>=0$, but I forgot the range is only up to $2/3$ for $x_i = (\theta + 3x_j)/8$. Thanks a ton. Can you try the problem in the link? I think I kinda got it, but I am not sure if my argument is indeed true.

Comment: McDonald: I have an additional question: from the best function you derived above, the reason we get $(2/3, 2/3)$ and $(1,1)$ as Nash equilibrium with $x_2\geq 2/3$ is because $b_1(2/3) = b_2(2/3) = [0,1]$ and $b_1(x_2 > 2/3) = b_2(x_1 > 2/3) = {1}$?

Answer (score 2):

It makes perfect sense. You can see that your payoff is strictly increasing in $x_i$ for $x_j > \frac{2}{3}$. When you took the derivative with respect to $x_i$ you got $3 x_j - 2$ which is strictly positive whenever $x_j > \frac{2}{3}$. Therefore, as a best response you should pick the highest possible value of $x_i$ which is given by 1.